# No me sirve DataTable

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

Buen dia,
Tengo un projecto en php y tengo una tabla que me trae datos de la base de datos y tengo el link de datatable, pero me sale la tabla con todos los registros hasta abajo y no me los almacena por paginacion.
Si se me pone responsive, pero es por boostrap pero datatable no me lo lee.
Alguien sabe porque?
Gracias de antemano.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="../library/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../library/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../library/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../library/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="../library/jquery/jquery.min.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="../library/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="../library/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="../library/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="../js/js1.js" defer=""></script>
<script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tabla').DataTable({

                "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
                    //"info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_ / Mostrados: _START_ de _END_ ",
                    "sInfo": "Mostrando: _START_ de _END_ - Total registros: _TOTAL_ ",
                    "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtrada de _MAX_ registros)",
                    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "processing": "Procesando...",
                    "search": "Buscar:",
                    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron registros coincidentes",
                    "paginate": {
                        "next": "Siguiente",
                        "previous": "Anterior"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [No me funciona DataTable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132698/no-me-funciona-datatable)

Comment: Pero nadie me responde

Comment: ¿Revisaste la consola de tu explorador?, si te muestra algún error.

Comment: Me sale esto `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Eso te ocurre porque estás incluyendo jQuery con `defer` y luego intentas llamar una función de jQuery (obsoleta, por cierto) antes de que se haya cargado la biblioteca. Para eso ya hay solución en el sitio y no es algo relacionado con DataTable

Comment: Como así entonces quito defer?

Comment: Entonces que hago alvaro?

Comment: ya lo arregle pero no me funciona la paginacion?

Comment: @Kygo pon una @ antes el nombre de la persona para que le llegue una notificación al escribir un comentario. No he visto que me habías respondido hasta hoy (porque la pregunta se ha marcado como duplicada)

Comment: Si ya solucionaste el problema, deberías ponerlo en las respuestas abajo para que sirva de ayuda a otros usuarios. Si la paginación falla, eso es un problema diferente y deberías crear una nueva pregunta

Comment: ya se soluciono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No me funcionaban porque tenia un defer en el script de DataTable al parecer pone problema con el script de DataTable, Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Pregunta. Alguno de estos link son del .js del dataTable?

```js
<script src="../library/jquery/jquery.min.js" defer=""></script>
<script src="../js/js1.js" defer=""></script>
```

De no ser así entonces debería de agregar el dataTable.js y referenciarlo.
Tampoco veo el script del dataTable, algo así.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable({  
                         
    "language": {
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
      //"info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_ / Mostrados: _START_ de _END_ ",
    "sInfo": "Mostrando: _START_ de _END_ - Total registros: _TOTAL_ ",
    "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
    "infoFiltered": "(filtrada de _MAX_ registros)",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron registros coincidentes",
    "paginate": {
    "next": "Siguiente",
    "previous": "Anterior"
  },
}
});
});
</script>
```

Donde '#myTable' es el nombre de su tabla.

Espero mi aporte sea de ayuda y de solución a su problema.

Comment: Es que ya le eh agregado scripts pero ni asi me cogen, y el primero si son de datatable, gracias.

Comment: Cuál es el archivo que llama el dataTable.js? y si lo estas llamando bien, me refiero a la ubicación del archivo

Comment: Ah ok ya edite los scripts.

Comment: Y ahora si le funcionó?

Comment: No tampoco me sigue sin dar resultado.

Comment: Verifique bien si el nombre del archivo .js del dataTable que esta referenciando es igual al nombre del archivo que tienes y verifica si la ruta es correcta, porque es raro que no funcione

Comment: Verifica también si el nombre de la tabla es igual al nombre que le pasas al script

Comment: quite o comente este link y pruebe <script src="../js/js1.js" defer=""></script>

Comment: No nada no me funciona quitandole ese script

Comment: comente esto también haber  <script src="../library/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" defer=""></script>

Comment: No aun así tampoco me funciona